# Elastic like search for python string?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I would like to search a given string

"movie.mp4"

With an arbitrary elasticsearch like search query like..

query: "mp4 OR mkv"

Is something like this achievable without archiving the string first?
I assume I would need to write my own function for this? Is there a library that exists for this?

Comment: Can you please share your mapping ? What did you try so far ? Did you take a look at bool queries & wildcard queries ?

Comment: Nono, I am not using elastic at all. I shouldnt have tagged it. I was wondering if I can use some query language lib on a raw string.